# How to add buttons in the same row as page controls

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

KendoUI Angular2 Grid: Is it possible to add buttons/controls in the same row as pagination control at the bottom of the grid? Is that a template that can be modified? I do not want to add buttons at the bottom of the grid and would like buttons at the same level as paging controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently templates for the Pager are not supported. What would be the case and how do you imagine this to work? Where should the template be placed? Open up an issue with your thoughts in [this repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2) for further discussion

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.